# AWS IoT Enterprise Button setup fails during Wi-Fi configuration and can't connect

Tags: wifi, amazon-iot-button

IoT button is able to connect to home Wi-Fi but not corporate Wi-Fi networks. Fails to connect to WPA2-Personal as well.
What kind of Wi-Fi networks does the AWS IoT enterprise button support and can connect?

We have been trying to perform claim and configure Wi-Fi steps using the "
AWS IoT 1-Click" app. After providing Wi-Fi SSID and password during the configuration steps, Setup goes to the final screen but Wi-Fi configuration fails and finish button is grayed out and doesn't become enabled.

[image: iPhone screenshot]

In the iPhone app, it says *Wi-Fi error -3.*